# Body text is overwriting a floating image

Tags: graphics, context-mkiv

I'm learning to use ConTeXt by formatting a document. I've run into a problem with wrapped graphics. The body text overlaps the image when I use the `{\bf text}` function on this line (inside the red circle below), but when I remove the `{\bf text}` and use just the text, the text doesn't overlap the image (image 2).

Can anybody help me retain the `{\bf text}` for this line without the text overlapping the image?

With bold line, with overlap:

[image]

Without bold line, no overlap:

[image]

Comment: Hard to figure out without a minimal example. Try `\dontleavehmode{\bf ....}` or using `\bold{....}` instead.

Comment: This question appears to be out of scope because the OP reported in a comment that the problem was solved (using a hint from another comment), and without a MWE it is not likely to be helpful to other users.